# netbeans : add library permanently

Tags: netbeans, relative-path, absolute-path

I work in a group project and after every checkout
I have to remove and add the javamail api..(because the path is relative)
how can i make it IN the Project folder?

This is how i add the library :

1. right click on librarys folder
2. Add/jar Folder..
3. Choose the mail.jar

But when my collegue checks this out... he get's problems.
How can i make the path absolute ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better way to add library to Netbenas would be

[Tools -> Libraries -> New Library...](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Adding_a_new_library_to_NetBeans)

After it:

Project tab -> [your project] -> Properties -> Libraries -> Add **Library**

This would be always "relative"

Comment: What also can be done is "Projects" tab, then "[your project] -> Libraries -> right-click -> Add Library..." and then select the library you just created with "Tools -> Libraries -> New Library..."  At least, this works for NetBeans 8.0.2 (don't know for previous versions of NetBeans).

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me: Project Properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder, and in that dialog there is a "Reference as" option. Choose "Relative Path" and then locate your library.

Comment: cool that I saw there we can also add src and javadoc path, and if both are on the same jar of the lib, it will work!

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using a *dedicated* folder for your libraries. Please see [this tutorial](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#projects-shared-libraries) to help doing the same. That way, the libraries can always live in their own country.

Comment: the tutorial changed/was moved, you mean we could just drop any lib on that folder and they would be auto detected and available?